# Flash actionscript 2.0 XML parsing works on some nodes, not others

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I'm working on a simple carousel.

My problem appears when trying to insert node values as text in my tooltip sub-elements.
Here's my xml:

```
<promotions>        
        <promotion>
            <visuel>/papyrus/8a8b8d2e26fa35b60126faf90a4d002f-20100223141718.gif</visuel>
            <remise>55</remise>

            <libelle>produit 1</libelle>
            <description>contenu test 1</description>
            <dateDebut>22/02/2010</dateDebut>
            <dateFin>10/03/2010</dateFin>
        </promotion>

        <promotion>
            <visuel>/papyrus/8a8b8d2e26fa35b60126faf9a2f30032-20100223141750.gif</visuel>

            <remise>15</remise>
            <libelle>Pneus</libelle>
            <description>Promo sur les pneus</description>
            <dateDebut>01/03/2010</dateDebut>
            <dateFin>01/05/2010</dateFin>
        </promotion>


        <promotion>
            <visuel>/papyrus/8a8b8d2e26fa35b60126fafa1fa5003a-20100223141955.gif</visuel>
            <remise>7</remise>
            <libelle>produit 1</libelle>
            <description>Test promo 1</description>
            <dateDebut>10/01/2010</dateDebut>
            <dateFin>10/03/2010</dateFin>
        </promotion>        
</promotions>
```

And here's the AS 2.0 where it's suppose to be loaded and inserted in the right moviclip and texts.

```
    xml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
   if(success) {
        var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;
        numOfItems = nodes.length;
        for(var i=0;i<numOfItems;i++)
        {
            var t = home.attachMovie("item","item"+i,i+1);
            t.angle = i * ((Math.PI*2)/numOfItems);
            t.onEnterFrame = mover;
            t.icon.inner.loadMovie(nodes[i].childNodes[0].firstChild);      
            t.promo= nodes[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
            t.produit= nodes[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
            t.dateDebut= nodes[i].childNodes[4].firstChild.nodeValue;
            t.dateFin= nodes[i].childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;
            t.icon.onRollOver = over;
            t.icon.onRollOut = out;
        }
 } else {
       trace("Unable to load XML");
   }   
}

function over()
{
    home.tooltip.promo.text = this._parent.promo;
    home.tooltip.produit.text = this._parent.produit;
    home.tooltip.tipDebut.text = this._parent.dateDebut;
    home.tooltip.tipFin.text = this._parent.dateFin;
    home.tooltip._x = this._parent._x;
    home.tooltip._y = this._parent._y + (this._parent._height*0.15);
    home.tooltip.onEnterFrame = Delegate.create(this,moveTip);
    home.tooltip._alpha = 100;
}
```

Results i'm having show me each gif picture (wich means i'm correctly pointing and loading the childnode), text contents load right ( node[libelle] and node[description]) buit nodes containing numbers or date don't load.
Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code, and it sort of works for me - although I can only guess about how your elements are set up on the stage.

Some things I did notice:

1. The path to each .gif file starts with a / which didn't work so well for me, but as you say, it's working for you...
2. The item0, item1, item2 movieClips are being added in front of the tooltip clip, so perhaps the images are obscuring your text? (but this could just be the way my stage is set up.)
3. This might be a dumb question, but have you embedded the full character set for your dynamic textfields? That might explain why letters are appearing but not numbers.

Also I don't know what your `mover`, `out` and `moveTip` functions are doing (can you maybe post them as well?).

Hope this helps a little...

Comment: Nope, the problem was on your third suggestion, i.e embedding special chars, and numbers, that's all. I got tyhat earlier yesterday, yet, thanks for the help.
So upvote,and thanks, you had it right.